# Count number of X in Column A when Y is in either Column B or C

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

Simplified data in columns A, B and C:

```
A | B | C
X |   | Y
  | Y |
X | Y |
Z |   | Y
X |   |
```

How to count the number of X when the value of Y is present in column B or C?
(ie. result is 2). Was thinking about `COUNTIFS` but can't seem to get the formula right :(

Comment: Can it ever have B AND C as Y?  If so, does that count as `1` or `2`

Comment: Y is either in B or C, never in both. However, Y may not be present at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a single `COUNTIFS`, because conditions in `COUNTIFS` are `AND`, not `OR`.  You *can* do it with multiple `COUNTIFS`, or an Array Formula (not recommended - that's a bit overkill for this case)

You need to count up all the rows where **Column A** is `X` and **Column B** is `Y`, add all the rows where **Column A** is `X` and **Column C** is `Y`, and *then* decide of a row where **Column A** is `X` and *both* **Column B** and **Column C** are `Y` is possible and/or should be counted twice.

If it is possible, but should **not** be double-counted, then you will need to *subtract* all the rows where **Column A** is `X` and **Columns B and C** are both `Y`.

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,"X",$B:$B,"Y") + COUNTIFS($A:$A,"X",$C:$C,"Y") - COUNTIFS($A:$A,"X",$B:$B,"Y"",$C:$C,"Y")
```

If it *can't* be in both, or you want that to count as 2 rows instead of 1, then you don't need the third `COUNTIFS`

As an Array Formula (using `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM`, because then we don't need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), for reference:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A:$A="X")*--(--($B:$B="Y")+($C:$C="Y")>0))
```

(The `>0` is so that the *OR* (`+`) doesn't double-count)

Comment: Because you are using math on the booleans you do not need all the `--` in the sumproduct.

Comment: @ScottCraner, yes `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5="X")*((B2:B5="Y")+(C2:C5="Y")))` works to give the same result.

Comment: Simply `=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="X")*(B:C="Y"))` would have done =)

Answer (score 1):

Because you never have a double-Y case, you can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="X")*(B1:B5="Y"))+SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="X")*(C1:C5="Y"))
```

[image]

Comment: Or simply `=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="X")*(B1:C5="Y"))` =)